# OneToMany Relationship: referenced id is null - spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring-Data-Jpa so my question is may a bit silly. I'm stuck and would be glad to get help.

I have a entity base model and two entities with following structure:

```java
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseModel {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
  private String id;
  
 ...more attributes + getter & setter
}
```

```java
@Entity
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project extends BaseModel {

  @Column 
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
          fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
          mappedBy = "project")
  private List<Announcement> announcements = new ArrayList<>();

  ...more attributes + getter & setter
}
```

```java
@Entity
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "announcement")
public class Announcement extends BaseModel {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="project_id", nullable = false)
  private Project project;

  ...more attributes + getter & setter
}
```

I persist my Project and Announcement Entity as follows:

```java
 public ProjectDTO createProject(CreateProjectRequest request) {
         Project projectEntity = projectRepository.save(
                Project.builder()
                        .announcements(request.getAnnouncements() != null
                                ? request.getAnnouncements().stream().map(dto -> modelMapper.map(dto, Announcement.class)).toList()
                                : null)
                        .history(List.of(
                                HistoryEntry.builder()
                                        .action(Action.PROJECT_CREATED.getValue())
                                        .build())
                        )
                        .status(Status.NEW)
                        .name(request.getName())
                        .build()
        );

        return modelMapper.map(projectEntity, ProjectDTO.class);
    }
```

I activated JPA SQL Statement trace with values.
Here you can see that the binding parameter 3 (foreign key for project) in the second statement is null. There is also no follow-up update in announcement entity for the foreign key value.

How can i fix that?

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert de.keycon.salesservice.model.entity.Project
        */ insert 
        into
            project
            (created, updated, name, status, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
09:36:32.263 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2022-11-29T09:36:32.254055300]
09:36:32.264 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2022-11-29T09:36:32.255054700]
09:36:32.264 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Demo-Project]
09:36:32.264 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [NEW]
09:36:32.264 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [2c9fe08184c287bc0184c287d3600000]
Hibernate: 
    /* insert de.keycon.salesservice.model.entity.Announcement
        */ insert 
        into
            announcement
            (created, updated, project_id, requirement, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
09:36:32.267 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2022-11-29T09:36:32.267443100]
09:36:32.267 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2022-11-29T09:36:32.267443100]
09:36:32.267 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
09:36:32.267 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [Java 11, Cloud Native Experience, Maven or Gradle, Experience with Testing Framework]
09:36:32.267 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [2c9fe08184c287bc0184c287d3730001]
```

EDIT:
I have already tried:

@JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference.

Change fetch.Lazy to fetch.Eager.

Set referencedColumnName = "id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question. I changed my `createProject` method to keep project also in announcements before persisting them. Now the id is correctly reflected.

```
public ProjectDTO createProject(CreateProjectRequest request) {
  List<Announcement> announcements = request.getAnnouncements() != null
    ? request.getAnnouncements().stream().map(dto -> modelMapper.map(dto, Announcement.class)).toList()
    : null;


  Project project = Project.builder()
    .announcements(announcements)
    .history(List.of(
      HistoryEntry.builder()
        .action(Action.PROJECT_CREATED.getValue())
        .build())
    )
    .status(Status.NEW)
    .name(request.getName())
    .build();

  for (var announcement: announcements) {
    announcement.setProject(project);
  }

  Project projectEntity = projectRepository.save(
    project
  );

  return modelMapper.map(projectEntity, ProjectDTO.class);
}
```